# Error : Implementation for method missing (Delphi Prism)

Tags: methods, implementation, delphi-prism, oxygene

I wrote my method: **LangChange**

```
type
  MainForm = partial class(System.Windows.Forms.Form)       
  private
      ...
      method LangChange();
protected
    method Dispose(disposing: Boolean); override;
  public    
    constructor;
  end;
implementation
...
method LangChange();
begin
...    
end;
```

However,I have an error
*Error 1 (PE33) Implementation for method "Compiler.MainForm.LangChange" missing*
What is wrong?Help please!

Answer (score 3):

LangChange is a method of the class MainForm so the implementation of the method should be

```
method MainForm.LangChange();
begin
end;
```